# How to pass multiple values back to jQuery AJAX handler?

Tags: jquery, ajax

I want to set the value a couple of form elements depending on the value selected from one select field with jQuery + PHP/MySQL.

The select field will call a jQuery function:

```
<select name="attr[8]" id="attr[8]"" onchange="set_watch_attr();">
  <option value="">auswählen</option>
  <option value="132185">116244</option>
</select>
```

Then it should set the values of the other select boxes based on the PHP/MySQL query result:

```
function set_watch_attr() {
  $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'set_watch_attr.php',
    data: 'ref=' + $("#attr[8]").val(),
    success: function(data) {
      data
    }      
  });       
}
```

The PHP field gets the values for this particular setting:

```
// set_watch_attr.php
<?php
  // process data and get default values

  // output to form
  $output = '
    $(\'#attr\\\[5\\\]\').val(157).change();
    $(\'#attr\\\[6\\\]\').val(12).change();
  ';
  echo $output;
?>
```

Somehow this is wrong as the output does not have any effect. I also tried to do it the other way around and placing the jquery change commands into JS, but the I could not retrieve the array which is needed to transmit multiple values back from the ajax call.

How can I manage to change multiple select fields upon one call?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `data` returned from the AJAX request is a string. You cannot just populate it with JS logic in your PHP code and execute it on the client side when the AJAX request completes, as you seem to be expecting.

To make this work I would suggest instead returning an object from your PHP code which is JSON encoded. The key/value pairs in this object being the id and value of the selects you wish to update.

Finally note that you should not be using `on*` event attributes. They are very outdated and should be avoided where possible. Use unobtrusive event handlers instead. As you're already using jQuery you can achieve all this with the following logic:

```html
<select name="attr[8]" id="attr[8]" class="set-watch">
  <option value="">auswählen</option>
  <option value="132185">116244</option>
</select>
```

```php
<?php
  $arr = array('#attr\\[5\\]'=>157,'#attr\\[6\]'=>12);    
  echo json_encode($arr);
?>
```

```js
$('.set-watch').change(function() {
  $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'set_watch_attr.php',
    data: { 
      ref: $(this).val() 
    },
    success: function(obj) {
      Object.keys(obj || {}).forEach(function(k) {
        $(k).val(obj[k]).change();
      }
    }      
  });         
}
```

Also note the common class placed on the `select` to make the selector more simple, and easier to re-use.

Comment: Interesting approach. I tried to implement, the jQuery code is missing 2 brakets, I added those but it will not cycle through the array. Instead it cycles through the string. alert(obj[k]); will output 37 alterts, starting with "#", followed by "a" and so on. alert(k); will ouput 37 alerts from 1-37. alert(obj); will output: "{"#attr\\[5\\]":157,"#attr\\[6\\]":12}"

Comment: @merlin Try to use a JSON.parse to objs before loop :)

Comment: I thought there must be some kind of json_decode somewhere :-) Thank you, works!